# Получение значения Scale из функции. Python, Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scale

Возник вопрос получения значения шкалы через функцию. Нашел один пример, но не смог понять откуда там необъявленный аргумент.

Откуда взялся аргумент `newVal`?
Если я захочу вызвать функцию `change` из другой функции, где взять этот аргумент? Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

````
root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x200")


def change(newVal):
    label["text"] = newVal


label = Label()
label.pack(anchor=NW)

scale = Scale(orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, from_=1.0, to=100.0, command=change)
scale.pack(anchor=NW)

root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Все что ты передашь в функцию, то и будет аргументом newVal. При change(5), newVal внутри функции будет равен 5.

Comment: newVal автоматически откуда-то подхватывает значение? Допустим, я создам функцию get_change() из которой буду вызывать change(). Что передать функции change() в качестве аргумента, чтоб получить значение Scale?
При детальном просмотре кода, там в scale передается параметр command=change, но в качестве параметра ничего не передается, однако значение в окне интерфейса рисуется корректное.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Для получения корректного значения, нужно в качестве аргумента newVal отправить scale.